# ¿Hay alguna libreria que me permita dibujar un gráfico de lineas en tiempo real con mas mil registros por segundo usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, real-time, charts

Necesito graficar un diagrama de lineas usando javascript y un archivo json que genera otro programa hecho en Java, este programa me devuelve el consumo energético del cpu, ram y package, lo cual genera miles de registros en un segundo, asi que necesito una libreria de javascript que me permita graficar dicha cantidad de datos, he probado con highcharts, pero funciona lento y algunas veces refresca la página y se pierde la continuidad de lo que se está graficando

Comment: Y realmente necesitas graficar miles de datos por segundo? Podrías simplemente reducir la lista generando la media en bloques de n valores para acortarla. Si son miles por segundo, calculando medias de 100 en 100 valores por ejemplo divides entre 100 el número de puntos a dibujar

Comment: Me piden que se grafiquen todos los datos conforme se van generando, ya que se desea conocer el consumo energético de ciertas aplicaciones, pero el programa que tengo desarrollado en Java genera una cantidad enorme de datos por lo cual se me está dificultando graficar dichos dato, pero presentaré la idea que me das, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que sería más rápido y eficiente para mostrar la gráfica? a) Realizar todos los cálculos en el servidor y enviar solo los resultados al navegador. b) Enviar todos los registros al navegador y que ahí se hagan los cálculos.